# I'm trying to run an AngularJS app with Sinatra and they're fighting over routing

Tags: angularjs, web, sinatra

My goal is to use angular to route pages so that I don't have to reload the whole page (like on https://www.inboxapp.com/).

My (abridged) sinatra:

```
get '/' do
  haml :index
end

get '/show' do 
  haml :show
end

get '/search/:id' do 
  # make http request and return data
end
```

and my angular:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/',
            controller: 'MainController'
        }).
        when('/search/:showId', {
            templateUrl: '/show',
            controller: 'ShowController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Again, the goal is to have / direct the user to /show without reloading the whole page (just changing the content in the middle). It's probably simple, but I'm quite new with angular (and front-end, in general), so any help is super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` ? If so need to mod rewrite to app entry point for virtual directories. If using hash only shouldn't have conflicts

Comment: I'm not using that, should I be? I don't quite understand the difference.

Comment: the difference is url's will look like normal directory paths if you use it. Otherwise they will have a `#` hash which servers ignore...like anchor hashes